# Issue creating password digest for Amadeus SOAP API

Tags: node.js, soap, hash, cryptography, amadeus

I followed the instructions in the docs and tried to do the same formula in Node, however, I'm not able to correctly authenticate with the server as I receive an `11|Session|` response. I assume that error is in response to incorrectly set nonce and/or password digest.

The formula: `Base64(SHA1($NONCE + $TIMESTAMP + SHA1($CLEARPASSWORD)))`

The variables: `$CLEARPASSWORD=AMADEUS`, `$TIMESTAMP=2015-09-30T14:12:15Z`, `$NONCE=c2VjcmV0bm9uY2UxMDExMQ==`.

The expected hash: `+LzcaRc+ndGAcZIXmq/N7xGes+k=`

The code I tried was:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(CLEARPASSWORD).digest() // Returns a buffer
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(NONCE + TIMESTAMP + hashedPassword).digest('base64') // Returns a Base64 String
```

However, this returns `DDcZEaS5AtoVaZhsARy9MqV+Y34=`. And if I change the nonce to its plain string `secretnonce10111`, then I get `gHOoqyDb9YJBrk30iabSO8nKxio=` which still isn't correct.

I'm not sure what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong. The problem was I was trying to concatenate a string with a Buffer, when I should have just made everything a buffer from the start.

So, instead of

```
const hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(CLEARPASSWORD).digest()
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(NONCE + TIMESTAMP + hashedPassword).digest('base64')
```

It should have been

```
const buffer = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(NONCE), Buffer.from(TIMESTAMP), nodeCrypto.createHash('sha1').update(CLEARPASSWORD).digest()])
const hashedPassword = nodeCrypto.createHash("sha1").update(buffer).digest("base64")
```